# spring based servlet web application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

There is a Spring based web application and servlet is only single. All requests are go through that servlet and I get beans in servlet before processing them later:

```
Application Context ctx = get contex...
and ctx.getBean("...")
```

So do I need to close Application Context in servlet?

It is not a Spring-MVC progect, it's just servets webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're turning off/on the web application within the Servlet container process, you should.

You can do this by loading the `ApplicationContext` within a `ServletContextListener` and adding it to the `ServletContext` with some constant attribute name. You can then retrieve it within your `Servlet`.
Finally, when the web application shuts down, you can use [`ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) to `close` to `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: What do you mean about "when the web application shuts down"? It is a web application which will be shutted down only if I reload server. Or maybe do you mean user session?

Comment: @Andy A Servlet container can maintain, dynamically, any number of web applications (servlet contexts). The container itself is a single `java` process, but it can be managing a number of web apps. You can shut down or turn on such web apps while the process is running. You'd want to `close` the `ApplicationContext` if you were to restart the webapp without killing the process. If you're going to kill the process, there's no (it really depends) point doing cleanup.

Comment: I actually get WebApplicationContext throw org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils but did not find any close method in it...

Comment: @andy This depends on the type of your application contexy. Not all of them have a close method.